# Xceed datagrid column visibility binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xceed-datagrid

I am trying to bind the visibility of columns in an Xceed datagrid to the IsChecked value of a checkbox.

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl ReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=ShowReferenceColumn, Path=IsChecked}">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Reference" Visible="{Binding ElementName=ShowReferenceColumn, Path=IsChecked}" />
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

The ReadOnly property of the datagrid is getting updated by the chaning of the checkbox IsChecked value, but the visibility of the column is not changing. Am I missing something in the binding on the column?

**Edit:**

The ReadOnly property here is an example of a property where I was able to get the binding to work. In reality it is not going to be binding to the same checkbox as used for the column visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="Reference" 
             Visible="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataGridControl.ReadOnly}" />
```

**Edit:**

> The `ReadOnly` property here is an example of a property where I was able to get the binding to work. In reality it is not going to be binding to the same checkbox as used for the column visibility.

Then you need to bind the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` to a source property of the view model and then bind the `Visible` property of the column to the same source property:

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="Reference" 
             Visible="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataGridControl.DataContext.BooleanSourceProperty}" />
```

You cannot use `ElementName` in this context as the column and the `CheckBox` don't belong to the same namescope.

Comment: The ReadOnly property is not going to be bound to the same property. I'll expand my question to make that clear

Comment: Then you need to bind the Checkbox to a source property and then bind the Visible property to the same source property. You cannot use ElementName in this context.

Comment: By source property, do you mean a property in my ViewModel? If so, I can see that that works, but I was hoping that I would not need to create a visibility bool property for each inidividual column

Comment: Yes, you need to store the value to bind to somewhere, i.e. in the view model. You cannot bind a column directly to a Checkbox control using ElementName. They are in totally different naming scopes.

Comment: If you want to update or write a new answer then I will accept

Answer (score 0):

Also met similar issue recently.

You can just utilize the **Visible** property, use the following generic approach and which is simple to understood:

```
<xcdg:ColumnFieldName="Reference" Title="Reference" 
Visible="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}, Path=DataGridControl.DataContext.BooleanSourceProperty}"/>
```

For example, if the *typeOfAncestor* is **xcdg:MergedColumn** and *BooleanSourceProperty* is **IsChecked**, then the code should be:

```
<xcdg:ColumnFieldName="Reference" Title="Reference"
Visible="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:MergedColumn}}, Path=DataGridControl.DataContext.IsChecked}"/>
```

Then the issue can be solved, sometimes if there is an exception "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.", the exception also can be avoided easily.

**Reference:**
https://xceed.com/forums/topic/Column-visible-binding-issue-MVVM/